# Change admin password alfresco share

Tags: passwords, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I can't login with my user administrator "admin" and I can't reset the password

I try to reset the password in Postgresql data base with this comande

UPDATE alf_node_properties SET string_value='f59601091e5cbb1dcf28bbb15a30c50b' WHERE node_id=4 and qname_id=12;

but don't resolve the problème !!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the correct Alfresco's reset password method ?
Things have changed since Alfresco 5.1, you might be doing it the wrong way.
You globally have [three ways to do it](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/admin-password.html) :

- Set a user with a known password as admin : 
  in `alfresco-global.properties` set the `alfresco_user_store.adminusername=username` property
- Configure the authentication component to accept all logins using `org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.SimpleAcceptOrRejectAllAuthenticationComponentImpl`
- Change the admin password in the DB (By following the correct alfresco's version instructions)